# File sharing web app using React and Node js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a file sharing web app using a MERN development stack.
While connecting my file sharing screen to my updating screen, I got stuck.

`ComponentsWillReceiveProps()` is not working in the current version of React. I tried to find an alternative and it showed either set 
`UNSAFE_ComponentsWillReceiveProps()` or use the function `static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)`, but I don't know how to define `prevState`.

My code is:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import _ from "lodash"
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class HomeUploading extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: null,
            event: null,
            loaded: 0,
            total: 0,
            percentage: 10,
        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const {data} = this.props;

        this.setState({
            data: data
        });

    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps,prevState){

        const {event} = nextProps;

        console.log("Getting an event of uploading", event,prevState);

        switch (_.get(event, 'type')) {
            case 'onUploadProgress' :
                const loaded = _.get(event, 'payload.loaded', 0);
                const total = _.get(event, 'payload.total', 0);
                const percentage = (total !== 0) ? ((loaded / total) * 100) : 0;

                this.setState ({
                    loaded: loaded,
                    total: total,
                    percentage: percentage
                });
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        this.setState({
            event:event,
        }) ;
    }

    render() {
        const {percentage, data, total, loaded} = this.state;
        const totalFiles = _.get(data, 'files', []).length;

        return (

            <div className={'app-card app-card-uploading'}>

                <div className={'app-card-content'}>
                    <div className={'app-card-content-inner'}>
                        <div className={'app-home-uploading'}>

                            <div className={'app-home-uploading-icon'}>

                                <i className={'icon-cloud-upload'}/>

                                <h2>Sending...</h2>

                            </div>

                            <div className={'app-upload-files-total'}>Uploading {totalFiles} files</div>
                            <div className={'app-progress'}>
                                <span style={{width: `${percentage}%`}} className={'app-progress-bar'}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className={'app-upload-stats'}>
                                <div className={'app-upload-stats-left'}>{loaded}Bytes/{total}Bytes</div>
                                <div className={'app-upload-stats-right'}>456K/s</div>
                            </div>
                            <div className={'app-form-actions'}>
                                <button className={'app-upload-cancel-button app-button'} type={'button'}>Cancel
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

HomeUploading.propTypes={
    data: PropTypes.object,
    event: PropTypes.object
}

export default HomeUploading;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing at the code, I'd refactor this a bit to keep this component as simple as possible (dumb/presentational component) that just displays new props as they're fed in.

Here's a description :https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/dumb-components-and-smart-components-e7b33a698d43

I'd suggest lifting the state up a level and doing the data transformation in the parent.

Something like this for the HomeUploading:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const HomeUploading = ({
  data,
  event,
  loaded,
  total,
  percentage,
}) => (
  <div className={'app-card app-card-uploading'}>
    <div className={'app-card-content'}>
      <div className={'app-card-content-inner'}>
        <div className={'app-home-uploading'}>
          <div className={'app-home-uploading-icon'}>
            <i className={'icon-cloud-upload'} />
            <h2>Sending...</h2>
          </div>

          <div className={'app-upload-files-total'}>Uploading {data.length} files</div>
          <div className={'app-progress'}>
            <span style={{ width: `${percentage}%` }} className={'app-progress-bar'} />
          </div>
          <div className={'app-upload-stats'}>
            <div className={'app-upload-stats-left'}>
              {loaded}Bytes/{total}Bytes
            </div>
            <div className={'app-upload-stats-right'}>456K/s</div>
          </div>
          <div className={'app-form-actions'}>
            <button className={'app-upload-cancel-button app-button'} type={'button'}>
              Cancel
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

HomeUploading.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object,
  event: PropTypes.object,
};

export default HomeUploading;
```

And then in the parent, you could have a the logic for transforming the data in a function:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Parent extends Component {

  state = {
    data: null,
    event: null,
    loaded: 0,
    total: 0,
    percentage: 0,
  }

  calcPercentage(loaded, total) {
    return (total !== 0) ? ((loaded / total) * 100) : 0
  }

  render() {
    const {
      data,
      event,
      loaded,
      total
    } from this.state;
    return (
      <HomeUploading 
        data={data}
        event={event}
        loaded={loaded}
        total={total}
        percentage={this.calcPercentage(loaded, total)}
      />
    );
  }

}

export default Parent;
```

This approach will give you the props updating without relying on `componentWillReceiveProps`.